# Error: Unknown filesystem

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I've seen several questions about this error, but all are related to either linux or dualboot of win and linux together.

I have Windows 7 on my Crucial 128 SSD drive, nothing special happened and after rebooting my machine I see this error:

```
error : unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

I have **only** Win7 on that machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: There used to be linux on your SSD drive.

Comment: @mdpc that is correct.. Since then I have formatted it and installed win7. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try booting from the Win7 DVD and running Startup Repair. *Something* must have happened for the bootloader to have gotten messed up.

Comment: @Karan tried this, didn't help.. it didn't find any issues.
I also trying reinstalling windows 7, when the setup reboots after compeleting the first few steps I got the same 'unknown filesystem'.. So I can't even re-install windows..

Comment: @Karan also tried loading the command line repair and running ``bootrec /fixmbr`` and ``bootrec /fixboot`` and still nothing.

Comment: From Win7 Setup, did you try deleting all partitions and then reformatting using NTFS?

Comment: @Karan I deleted the single partition that was there and installed it on that unallocated partition. Do you think it would make a difference if I tried again and choose to format the partition instead of just deleting it and installing on the unpartitioned space?

Comment: No, Setup would have created a partition and formatted it anyway. Strange, I would have thought that would suffice to get rid of Grub. BTW, do you have other drives in the system? Can you try booting with only the SSD connected?

Comment: I have another drive connected but I am 100% sure it's not trying to load that one since I have manually selected the SSD from the boot order manager. What else can I do?

Comment: Try disconnecting the other drive nevertheless. It is entirely possible that your OS is on one drive, and the bootloader on another.

Comment: @Karan just did that, still getting the same error message.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you first try Startup Repair again without reconnecting the other drive. If that doesn't help, I'd recommend a reinstall with just the SSD connected, again deleting the existing partitions and emptying the drive first. Once this completes successfully there's no way Grub should persist.

Comment: @Karan OK, no idea what solved it but after disconnecting the other HD and deleting the current partitions and creating the new partition (win7 also created another partition for 'system' stuff) and it works now.. Thanks!!!